# how to modify collection if I have indexes of elements to be removed and list of elements to add?

Tags: algorithm, collections

I have such function

```
applyDiff(List orders, List ordersToAdd, int[] ordersToRemove) {
}
```

This function should add orders from `orderToAdd` to `orders` and remove some orders from `orders`, indexes of orders to be removed are passed in `ordersToRemove` array.

The problem is: every time order from `ordersToAdd` is inserted into `orders` somewhere at position `pos`, all indexes from `orderToRemove` that a greather than `pos` must be increased at `1`.

So should I dinamically modify `ordersToRemove` array?

What is general "algorithm" or modifing a collection when I should at the same time add-remove elements and I have indexes of elements to be removed?

Note I can not break this task at two (orders adding, orders removing) because the order is very important and function inside it decides in what order orders should be added and removed.

Comment: You can remove first object then add objects in collection.

Comment: @Romil: according to his last requiremenet, it cannot be done.

Comment: right. also I forgot to say that at any point modifications can be stopped and I need copy of `orders` indicating most recent state. So it's also not possible to calculate "final" orders and then just do work. I.e. at any point of modifications i need **current** state.

Comment: What is the order of addition and deletion? Are you working on both lists simultaneously?

Comment: @dirkgently that's right. and we should not rely on order of addition and deletion as it could be changed in future.

Comment: @javapowered: If the order of addition/deletion is unknown, how do you start off iterating over either collection? Your question needs some more clarification. Can you show us some psuedo-code as to how you expect things to work (forget the index updation logic for the moment).

Comment: @dirkgently assume that I randomly mix "order add" and "order delete" and then executing updates one by one.

Comment: @dirkgently But I understand why you ask this question and this is good question... I think I will add another function that will create List<OrderUpdate> where OrderUpdate is either add or remove and this list will be processed one by one.. well probably I should rethink my entire question. I likely should introduce one extra int[] array in which I will store how much I should add to convert original index to current index..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified explicitly how do you determine at which positions exactly you insert, neither what is the semantics of `int[] ordersToRemove` (though for the latter I assume it is indices of objects to remove considering your notes). However I can still suggest an "algorithm" and you will apply it accordingly:

Introduce one more variable in you method `indexIncrease`. Initialize it to `0`. Every time you add to `ordersToAdd` increase this variable. Every time you consider a value from `int[] ordersToRemove` do not just consider this value, but rather consider `ordersToRemove[i] + indexIncrease`. Thus you will get your updated value from `ordersToRemove` without the need of iterating of over the whole array and increasing the values after each addition.

Note that applying this "alogrithm" you ensure that the list `orders` is always in its current state, but the `ordersToRemove` will not be updated at all. hopefully this will work for you.

**EDIT** As per the comments and the completely changed problem description:

- You can spare the looping through all the elements of `ordersToRemove` if you use [binary index tree](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees). With it every modification becomes `O(log n)` in complexity, where n is the total number of orders that will exist.
- considering the input limitations you give the index tree is a lot worse than the brute force solution you already have: the number of elements to iterate every time is neglectably small, the performance drawback is neglectable and the index tree is too much of spurious complexity.

As seen overall: **I advise you to stick with the current solution**.

Comment: i need `orders` in current state at any step. I only modify `orders`. I don't care what happens with `ordersToAdd` or `ordersToRemove`, in particular I can modify them if needed. I don't understand how just introducing one extra `int` variable I can solve entire problem.. Orders are inserted into `orders` at some positions. Sometimes at the beggining sometimes in the middle. So some indexes from `ordersToRemove` should be increased, but some should not.

Comment: @javapowered: nope I don't agree with that. What is the order in which you execute the operations. In your problem description you call just one method. The only possibility I can think of is that you start inserting from lowest indices and increase them gradually. Can you be a bit more explicit on the order of operation execution. Please also add input limit constraints.

Comment: order of operations execution depends on `order price`, `order volume`, `currently available limits` so we can assume that there are not particular order. there are not to much orders or orderUpdate (add or delete). not more than 10.

Comment: well probably my entire question is incorrect. question should be more  precise

Comment: I marking you answer as correct for now so people can stop tring to answer my question. It seems it a little bit complicated and not clear enough. I should try to implement something I guess and then ask more certain questions.